# S-lock in a process executing single select

Tags: sql-server, profiling, deadlock

I have a deadlock between 2 processes, **processd38f8748** (1st) and **process5b2988**(2nd).

The 1st process is a `SELECT` that runs in a separate connection. No explicit transaction has been opened in code for it. There are no sql-requests that may have run before or after this `SELECT` in the same connection. This select needs aquiring shared-lock on page 356615.

The 2nd process is an `UPDATE` and it already holds an IX lock on a page 356615 (it's difficult to identify the exact place in system, but i can believe that) while it wants another page 356614. Everything OK here.

Now, the strange thing is that 2nd process can't get the lock on page 356614, because it's already being held by 1st process.

This is strange for me for 2 reasons:

- i'm pretty sure that this select is the only request in sql-connection
- the IL is readcommited. I thought that for this IL all S-locks are released once the statement finishes.

Here is the deadlock xml.

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="processd38f8748">
  <process-list>
   <process id="processd38f8748" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:356615" waittime="2369" ownerId="24096354927" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2013-03-06T11:26:10.810" XDES="0x368701960" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="5756" status="suspended" spid="60" sbid="0" ecid="11" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2013-03-06T11:26:10.810" lastbatchcompleted="2013-03-06T11:26:10.810" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CWCEINAW" hostpid="2604" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="24096354927" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x02000000dffc7a241f9433fddb83b7f97a7c0369dbf6d467">
SELECT TOP 1 1
                FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction] AS [ST]
                    LEFT JOIN [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] AS [STL] ON ( [STL].[StockTransaction_id] = [ST].[id] )
                WHERE
                    [ST].[Status] IN (0, 1) AND
                    [ST].[Type] = 0 AND
                    ([ST].[StockContainerID] = 300000120244 OR [STL].[StockContainer_id] = 300000120244)     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process5b2988" taskpriority="0" logused="17268" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:356614" waittime="2264" ownerId="24096354521" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-03-06T11:26:10.690" XDES="0x80021040" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="2" kpid="5832" status="suspended" spid="55" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-03-06T11:26:10.920" lastbatchcompleted="2013-03-06T11:26:10.920" lastattention="2013-02-28T11:26:25.940" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CWCEINAW" hostpid="2604" loginname="cwcuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="24096354521" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="702" sqlhandle="0x02000000f0a38d32edae20f54b42cd640b8022448db200b7">
UPDATE [WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction] SET [type] = @type, [status] = @status, [startdate] = @startdate, [enddate] = @enddate, [totalquantity] = @totalquantity, [totalvalue] = @totalvalue, [totalweight] = @totalweight, [datecreated] = @datecreated, [dateupdated] = @dateupdated, [stockorder_id] = @stockorder_id, [site_id] = @site_id, [stockowner_id] = @stockowner_id, [stocklocation_id] = @stocklocation_id, [stockcontainerid] = @stockcontainerid, [uid] = @uid, [machinenumber] = @machinenumber, [editor_id] = @editor_id WHERE [id] = @id     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@type int,@status int,@startdate datetime,@enddate datetime,@totalquantity int,@totalvalue decimal(6,2),@totalweight decimal(5,5),@datecreated datetime,@dateupdated datetime,@stockorder_id bigint,@site_id int,@stockowner_id int,@stocklocation_id int,@stockcontainerid bigint,@uid uniqueidentifier,@machinenumber nvarchar(1),@editor_id int,@id bigint)UPDATE [WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction] SET [type] = @type, [status] = @status, [startdate] = @startdate, [enddate] = @enddate, [totalquantity] = @totalquantity, [totalvalue] = @totalvalue, [totalweight] = @totalweight, [datecreated] = @datecreated, [dateupdated] = @dateupdated, [stockorder_id] = @stockorder_id, [site_id] = @site_id, [stockowner_id] = @stockowner_id, [stocklocation_id] = @stocklocation_id, [stockcontainerid] = @stockcontainerid, [uid] = @uid, [machinenumber] = @machinenumber, [editor_id] = @editor_id WHERE [id] = @id    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="356615" dbid="7" objectname="Eindhoven_CWC.dbo.WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction" id="lock10f24cb00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594093830144">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process5b2988" mode="IX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processd38f8748" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="356614" dbid="7" objectname="Eindhoven_CWC.dbo.WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction" id="lock17e539e00" mode="SIU" associatedObjectId="72057594093830144">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processd38f8748" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process5b2988" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like different access order between reader and writer. I would expect that the update does exactly one single seek for the `[Id] = @id` but the very fact that it has a page and wants another one indicates a scan. Do you have an index on `[Id]` ?

Comment: Yes, off course. The process HAS the pagelock because some previous statement in transaction resulted in a scan. It probably only WANTS to take a single rowlock for an update, but it cant since the whole page is taken by another process (a select. I don't know why...)

Comment: process5b2988 has page 356615 in IX and wants 356614 also in IX. Ie. the update itself is looking at *two* pages with IX. Is `[Id]` unique? Or is the UPDATE xact doing more than one update, on different `[ID]`s?

Comment: Yes, [id] is PK. I suppose that page 356615 was taken not by this update, but by some previous statement(s) within same transaction.

Comment: If you do `UPDATE ... WHERE ID = 1` and `UPDATE ... WHERE ID = 2` in the same xact you are going to deadlock. Readers (as well as other updates) *must* lock the IDs in the same order (1->2). But practically is impossible to ensure all readers will also lock first `1` and second `2` (including all joins in any query plan...), so deadlocks are unavoidable.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But I expected that a single `select` either puts locks on both pages simultaneosly or waits for update batch to finish. Now I see that a single select (still unfinished) already issued one pagelock and wants another one.

Comment: Is impossible to requests two locks simultaneously. When you magnify close enough everything gets decomposed to small serial tasks.